# Who is the server in arduino ethernet shield?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I want your help in this arduino project please
I made this project tow days ago and it worked fine
but my question is : who is the server and who is the client ?
I am not good in networking
hope you can help me

https://www.instructables.com/id/Remote-Home-Automation-Example-Arduino-Etherne/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Arduino is a server. It take a static html page.

Client is your browser.

Comment: OK, thank you very much.